# Data sharing Between Programs

Tags: java

i Have a matrix mat[ ][ ], and 3 Java programs node1.java node2.java node3.java. 
each program has addElement(i,j,x) which updates mat[i][j]=x and 
getElement(i,j) which returns x=mat[i][j],

I want mat[ ][ ] should be common  between all three java programs. and data added by one node can be retrieved from other node.

Note : node1.java node2.java node3.java are 3 seperate java files
Please Help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: That sounds as you want to use JEE and an application server.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want threads and a synchronized monitor? Or maybe a server solution? Only ideas I can think of that would work.

Comment: ice, corba, database, shared files, choose one

Comment: various options you have are : storage in file, database, static matrix in one of the classes(not recommended much), multithreadd program etc. choose one wisely

Comment: @Uwe Plonus : JEE Server will become complex for me.

Comment: @MartinLarsson : All 3 nodes run Threads, and Hence they continuously update the matrix. All Three are in infinite Loop. For this Any Idea?

Comment: @GirishMantha an approach without an application server will become at least as complex.

Comment: @user902383 : Hi, All 3 java classes override Thread, So They are in Infinite Loop changing the matrix continuously. Please Give an Idea About Sharing in File as other options will increase complexity of the program.

Comment: @UwePlonus : If i Have Application server, still i should go far DATABASE/ SHARED FILE. Any simpler Approach?

Comment: @MartinLarsson : synchronized java monitors are used to share data(variable) within the program as described in example program like accessing correct value between deposit(x) and access(x). My problem is between different Programs.

Comment: @GirishMantha from your comments it is now unclear if you have 3 threads in one program or 3 different programs (in different processes).

Comment: @tejas : How to do using static matrix method as i have 3 different java programs.. please help !!

Comment: @UwePlonus : 3 different programs(in different processes). One Thread per node. Ex : 
Class node1 { 
run(){ 
addElement(){..}
getElement(){..}
 } 
psvm() 
{ 
Thread s= new Thread(new node1()) 
} 
}

Comment: @Girish Mantha you said three classes, are three independent threads, or three independent programs? if you want to do this by sharing files each first you need lock the file to prevent other threads/apps to use it, update it and unlock it. when i has similar issue, i used tcp to communicate between process(i had two so it was much easier) or you can use ice which i think its best way to go for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can have a static matrix in one of the classes

```
public class Node1{
public static int[][] mat=new int[10][10];
}
```

and whenever you do any operations on it in any of the classes, use

```
update(int i,int j,int x){
Node1.mat[i][j]=x;
}
```

instead of storing this static matrix in one of the classes, you can make one Global.java class and store matrix in it.

This is not a much recommended way of doing it, but still might work for you. The assumption here is that all of the 3 programs of your are running at the same time. This would fail otherwise

Comment: I Just Tried by above mentioned method..
public class array implements Runnable {
public static int[] a=new int[100];
run { //do nothing }
psvm(){
thread t= new Thread (new array())
t.start() }

public class addToArray implements Runnable {
run { array.a[0]=10 }
psvm(){
thread s= new Thread (new addToArray())
s.start() }

public class readFromArray implements Runnable {
run { System.out.println(array.a[0]); }
psvm(){
thread u= new Thread (new readFromArray())
u.start() }

Above Printing 0.ALL 3 programs ll be running infinitely as i have put a while loop in run method after some delay.

Comment: Sorry its difficult to read and understand. How to post Like as you posted? Help !!

Comment: add an edit to your question ! you will find formatting tools there, in the comment box you won't have any formatting

Answer (score 0):

Use [Terracotta](http://terracotta.org/) or [Hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com/) (or any other distributed in-memory technology).

Comment: Checked those 2 links, Which i found no way connected to my question. Sorry.!!

Comment: You're looking for shared mutable state between different Java processes. These processes need a way to communicate. You can either code the communication layer all by yourself (files, databases or socket connections) or you take an existing solution which handles this. Take a look at the getting started tutorial in Hazelcast, maybe this helps to clear things up a bit: http://www.hazelcast.com/screencast.jsp

Comment: Thank you. Trying to customize my app using hazelcast.